# Xcode 8 Table View Cells to Different Views

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am having trouble with linking `view controllers` to table view `cells`. Basically I have 4 `cells` in my `Table View`, and I want each cell to `present` a separate `view controller` when clicked.

Here are my swift codes:

```
import UIKit

var orchard = ["Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Fish"]
var myIndex = 0

class AnimalList: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return orchard.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = orchard[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        myIndex = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Here is my storyboard, as you can see I have 4 `view controllers` that I want to connect to the 4 `table view cells`.
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjypj.png)

PS: My `table view controller` has already been embedded inside a `navigation controller`.

How do I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Embedded your `TableViewController` in `Navigation Controller` ( Most probably , you already did ) .

[image]

2. Select Yellow marked `TableViewController` click `Right Mouse` hold and put it to a view controller , release and select Manual Segue -> Show

[image]

3. Now select segue and rename it with unique Identifier . For every view controller repeat steps 2 & 3  .

   [image]
4. Update `tableView didSelectRowAt` delegate  function like below .

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: orchard[indexPath.row], sender: self)
}`

Comment: Thank you for such detailed tutorial, it worked perfectly!

Comment: so nice to hear , it helped you :) @Qin

Answer (score 2):

Give a segue for the four `ViewControllers` and name it as `vc1Segue`, `vc2Segue`, `vc3Segue`, `vc3Segue`

And change your `didSelectRowAt` method like below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    switch myIndex {
          case 0:
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "vc1Segue", sender: self)
          case 1:
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "vc2Segue", sender: self)
          case 2:
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "vc3Segue", sender: self)
          case 3:
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "vc4Segue", sender: self)
        default:
            print("Index greater than vcs")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just now i done demo project with your requirements its working perfectly.

Step1: Prepare your story board as shown in below image.

[image]

step2: Give storyboard identifiers as dogID,catID,birdID,fishID to the respective viewController as shown in below image.
[image]
step3: Declare an array with the above identifiers just below your arched array.

```
var storyboardIds = ["dogID","catID","birdID","fishID"]
```

step4: Modify your didSelectRowAt method as shown in below code snippet.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    myIndex = indexPath.row

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIds[myIndex]) {

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a segue for each of the 4 view controllers by ctrl+right click and dragging from table view controller to each of the view controllers. Give an identifier to the segues (e.g. "TableToViewController1", "TableToViewController2", etc)

Then in your `didSelectRowAt` do something like:

```
var segueIdentifier = ""

switch(indexPath.row) {
case 0: // first cell is selected
    segueIdentifier = "TableToViewController1"
case 1:
    segueIdentifier = "TableToViewController2"
case 2:
    segueIdentifier = "TableToViewController3"
case 3:
    segueIdentifier = "TableToViewController4"
}

performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is inside your

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}
```

`func` you can check which `index` it is and based on that `present` the `viewController` you want.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    if let animal = orchard[indexPath.row] as String? {
        if animal == "dog" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "dogViewController", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

In your `storyboard` you would create a `segue` from the `viewController` to all ur `viewControllers` and name the segues with something like `dogViewController` etc.